# react-router-dom: pass a variable with css to NavLink's activeStyle prop? (Emotion)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, emotion

When using react-router-dom's Navlink's `activeStyle` prop, how can I extract the styles to a variable so that I don't have to repeat the same styles over and over again without using a css file?

Ideally, I'd like to do this with `Emotion` (without just doing an **styled.Navlink**), but if that's not possible, a regular variable would be ok as well.

My file looks like this:

```
import { NavLink, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { css } from '@emotion/react';

const navLinkStyle = css({
   color: blue,
});

const navLinkActiveStyle = { // also tried css({ ... })
  color: 'red',
};
```

With this element below:

```
   <NavLink
      to='/home'
      // activeClassName='selected' // I imagine this is for pure css styling, not css-in-js.
      css={navLinkStyle} // Emotion css prop
      activeStyle={navLinkActiveStyle} // Does not seem to accept any variable (emotion's or regular)
    >
      Home
   </NavLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign all the styles to an object.

```
const navLinkStyle = {
        color: 'blue',
        backgroundColor:'green',
        ...etc
    };
```

And use this object like

```
 <NavLink
  to='/home'
  activeStyle={navLinkStyle} 
>
  Home
</NavLink>
```